# Or on Query not working

Tags: sql

I am having a problem with the last select statement, the OR. what we want is to include 
records who have TIER = T1 but only if the have a COST > 500 and skilllevel = 'S'. but this code of last line only has to be an OR. AND  will leave out most of the records.

```
 Insert Into @tblMain
    Select  * from (
            SELECT distinct a.ID_KEY,a.STAT, a.TIER, f.FACILITY_ID,  f.FACILITY_NAME Name, a.RX, a.PATIENTNAME, a.MEDICATION , (a.COST) as Cost, (a.COST) as Interchanges,  s.Savings Savings
            FROM[PBM].[T_CHARGES] a 
            --Inner Join  PBM.FACILITY f on a.FACILITYNPI = f.FACILITY_NPI 
            inner Join PBM.PHARMACY_NPI pn on a.PHARMACYNPI = pn.NPI
            Inner join PBM.PHARMACY_FACILITY pp on pn.PHARMACY_ID = pp.PHARMACY_ID
            inner Join PBM.FACILITY f on pp.FACILITY_ID = f.FACILITY_ID AND a.FACILITYNPI = f.FACILITY_NPI
            Left Outer Join @TableSum s on a.ID_KEY = s.ID_KEY 
            where f.FACILITY_NAME is not null 
            and month(a.DATEDISPENSED) = @Month and year(a.DATEDISPENSED) = @Year        
            and f.FACILITY_ID = @FacilityId
            and a.STAT not in (3,4,5) 
             and (TIER <> 'T1' )
            --OR (TIER = 'T1' AND COST>500 AND SKILLLEVEL = 'S' )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server will respect parentheses for order of evaluation, which I think you need:

```
...
AND 
(
   (TIER <> 'T1')
   OR 
   (TIER = 'T1' AND COST>500 AND SKILLLEVEL = 'S')
)
```

Answer (score 5):

By default in sql server `NOT` takes precedence over `AND` , `AND` takes precedence over `OR`

```
   NOT --> AND --> OR
```

to enforce an order other than default you can make use of Parenthesis.

```
...........
and f.FACILITY_ID = @FacilityId
and a.STAT not in (3,4,5) 
and (  
          (TIER <> 'T1') 
       OR 
          (TIER = 'T1' AND COST > 500 AND SKILLLEVEL = 'S' )
    )
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to add parentheses. You can also drop `TIER = 'T1'` sub-condition, because if `TIER` is not `'T1'`, the check for `<>` would succeed, making the `OR` `true` regardless of the additional check:

```
AND ((TIER <> 'T1') OR (COST > 500 AND SKILLLEVEL = 'S'))
```